# Remove the gray area from a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I have a DataGridView that is showing some gray areas that I cannot remove. I have set the following options for the datagrid...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim x As New DataGridView
        x.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
        x.RowHeadersVisible = False
        x.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        x.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        x.AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
        x.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        x.AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
        x.AllowUserToResizeRows = False
        x.ReadOnly = True
        x.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
        x.Columns.Add("Header1", "Header1")
        x.Columns.Add("Header2", "Header2")

        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            x.Rows.Add(New String() {"VALUES", "I AM NUMBER " & i})
        Next
    Me.Controls.Add(x)
    End Sub
```

I cannot make the width of the DataGridView go any smaller because I tried doing `DataGridView.Width -= 5` and it doesn't go any smaller.

I do not want to set the BackColor to control or transparent because that's still going to have the border, it will just be invisible. I need the gray area actually gone and only be left with the size of whatever the column and rows are.

**UPDATE**:
With the updated* code above, the GridView does not expand its height enough to fit all the data, I do not want to use a scrollbar, I want it to be able to show all the rows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Dim w As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) +
                                  DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth + 
                                  2 * DataGridView1.BorderStyle

DataGridView1.Width = w

Dim h As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) +
                                 DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + 
                                 2 * DataGridView1.BorderStyle

DataGridView1.Height = h
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi dear you only need to do is to change the property of the datagridview

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```

Thats it

Comment: Hello, I took out the `DataGridView1.AutoSize = True` but the height of but gridview does not expand to fit the rows I add?

Comment: Just put in my code into yours and it will gona work

Comment: Try to dock the datagridview to the form and it will show

Comment: The DataGrid becomes big if I fill it and have too many white space. The row become too long.

Comment: Soo then change the size of the form to the correct amount but of course if you want to put anything else on that form then we need to find another solution

Comment: Is there a way to automatically change the size of the form to the size of the DataGridView so I don't have to change it manually?

Comment: You can get the size of the datagridview and put it into an integer then you can use the integer to set the form size

Comment: I used a panel instead to test and it doesn't seem to work. I set `Panel1.Size = DataGridView1.Size` and `DataGridView.Dock = Fill` but the DatagridView is still getting cut off. https://i.imgur.com/cAGOqZy.png

Comment: First put the size of the datagridview into an integer (You need 1 for x and 1 for y)